# Условия в чанках modx revolution

Tags: modx

Мне в чанке надо прописать условие: если нет фоновой картинки - выводить цвет фона, иначе выводить картинку. Установил плагин "IF". Пишу так:

```
style="[[!If? &subject=`[[+tv.bgImage]]` &operator=`==` &operand=`empty` &then=`background-color:[[+tv.bgColor]]` &else=`background-image:url([[+tv.bgImage]])`"
```

tv.bgImage и tv.bgColor - это переменные, которые отвечают за картинку и цвет фона. Результут - все что после **style="** не выводится. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае, плагины не нужны, используйте модификаторы вывода:

```
style="[[+tv.bgImage:is=``:then=`background-color:[[+tv.bgColor]]`:else=`background-image:url([[+tv.bgImage]])`]]"
```

https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/input-and-output-filters-(output-modifiers)

Comment: спасибо, работает